# providing positive numbers with Moq

Tags: moq, mstest

I am trying to provide positive number using It class in Moq:

```
It.Is<int>(a => a > 0)
```

But the result is always equals to 0. What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you share a complete example? When you say "to provide" it sounds like you want to setup `Returns` instead of `It.Is<int>` which is used for parameter matching.

Comment: I am using in the context of parameter matching: var result = await sut.Get(It.Is<int>(a => a > 0));

Comment: `It.Is<int>(a => a > 0)` always return default value, in the case of int it is 0, it is expected. You should not use this construct to invoke methods of sut, you could but then expect default value, but to setup the mocks...

Comment: Thanks @Johnny - actually I am trying to setup a mock with a positive number, what is the point of letting you to specify a function to match the argument when it is not respected and always returns default value? Just wondering.

Comment: I have a feeling you are missing `.Returns(numberYouWantToBeReturned)`...Could you post the method you are trying to setup and the test...

Comment: I posted the method in comments above - await sut.Get(It.Is<int>(a => a > 0)); Need to test the behaviour when the argument is positive number

Comment: But then just invoke it with positive number like, `await sut.Get(1)`

Comment: You're right, maybe I am overthinking

Answer (score 0):

It sounds your test is a bit low-level and that you should be testing the logic of the code that performs actions based on the values it receives rather than the values themselves. With that said, here is some code which might help. It wraps the built-in .NET random number generator to ensure that a known sequence of numbers is output.

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyMultipleValues()
{
    // Define values to return
    var values = new[] {5, 9, 10};

    // Create a mock of the interface
    var mockRand = new Mock<IRandomNumber>();
    // Define behaviour of the mock
    mockRand.Setup(m => m.GetRand(It.IsAny<int>())).ReturnsInOrder(values);
    // Point the factory output at the mock object
    DomainFactory.RandomNumber = mockRand.Object;

    // Create an instance of the wrapper object
    // The wrapper calls the factory which in turn calls the mock object that was just created
    // to return known values
    var wrapper = new Wrapper();
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        var output = wrapper.GetNumber(100);
        Assert.AreEqual(v, output);
    }

    // Clean up
    DomainFactory.RandomNumber = null;
}
```

ReturnsInOrder is an extension method sourced from [here](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/24/moq-sequences-revisited.aspx/).

```
public static void ReturnsInOrder<T, TResult>(this ISetup<T, TResult> setup,
  params TResult[] results) where T : class
{
    setup.Returns(new Queue<TResult>(results).Dequeue);
}
```

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
// Interface
public interface IRandomNumber
{
    int GetRand(int end);
}

// Implementation
public class RandomNumber : IRandomNumber
{
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

    public int GetRand(int end)
    {
        return _random.Next(0, end);
    }   
}

// Factory
public static class DomainFactory
{
    private static IRandomNumber _randomNumber;
    public static IRandomNumber RandomNumber
    {
        get { return _randomNumber ?? (_randomNumber = new RandomNumber()); }
        set { _randomNumber = value; }
    }
}

// Wrapper
public class Wrapper
{
    public int GetNumber(int parameter)
    {
        return DomainFactory.RandomNumber.GetRand(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Malice! Actually, I am testing a controller method that has an int argument. If argument is negative or zero, than the expected result is a validation error. Otherwise, if argument is positive, than the expected result should be of type OkObjectResult. I'd rather provide a hardcoded int value for the case with positive int.